# Flask deployed with Kubernetes: socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I am trying to get my head wrapped with Kubernetes so I wrote a simple App. It works fine on my computer, however after Deploying with Kubernetes, the app can not start. This is how the code looks like:

```
import uuid

import flask
from flask import Flask

hostname = str(uuid.uuid4())
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return flask.render_template('index.html', hostname=hostname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0:5000')
```

Deploying the app with docker:

```
FROM python:3.9.0a5-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
kubectl logs flask-debugger-696c587755-d64rg
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0:5000')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 996, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 847, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

What is the problem?

Comment: According to the docs `port` is a separate parameter to `app.run()`

Comment: @IainShelvington that was the problem, thank you

Comment: @LongNguyen please consider posting the solution as an answer so others can benefit from it whenever they come across same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import uuid

import flask
from flask import Flask

hostname = str(uuid.uuid4())
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return flask.render_template('index.html', hostname=hostname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

@iain-shelvington is right .its port parameter issue.